# $.getJSON only works on Edge browser but not Chrome or IE

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying get data from a json file using $.getJSON. However, the code only works on Edge browser but not any other bowers and I have no idea at all. Please see the code below:

```
function CreateTableFromJSON(){
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON("wellness.json", function (data) {

        var cars = new Array("Athlete", "Muscle-Soreness", "Sleep-Quality");

        var arrItems = [];      // THE ARRAY TO STORE JSON ITEMS.
        $.each(data, function (index, value) {
            arrItems.push(value);
        });

        // EXTRACT VALUE FOR TABLE HEADER.
        var col = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < arrItems.length; i++) {
            for (var key in arrItems[i]) {
                if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                    col.push(key);
                }
            }
        }

        // CREATE DYNAMIC TABLE.
        var table = document.createElement("table");

        var tr = table.insertRow(-1);                   // TABLE ROW.

        for (var i = 0; i < arrItems.length; i++) {
            var th = document.createElement("th");      // TABLE HEADER.
            th.innerHTML = cars[i];
            tr.appendChild(th);
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {

            tr = table.insertRow(-1);
            for (var j = 0; j < arrItems.length; j++) {
                var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
                tabCell.innerHTML = arrItems[j][col[i]];
            }
        }



        // FINALLY ADD THE NEWLY CREATED TABLE WITH JSON DATA TO A CONTAINER.
        var divContainer = document.getElementById("showData");
        divContainer.innerHTML = "";
        divContainer.appendChild(table);
    });
});
```

}

Hi guys, I am trying get data from a json file using $.getJSON. However, the code only works on Edge browser but not any other bowers and I have no idea at all.

Comment: Does the code throw any errors?

Comment: `insertCell` has somewhat lacking support in everything but IE/Edge

Comment: Using correct JSON returns the data back [**as expected**](https://jsfiddle.net/L2ufeabg/) using `.getJSON`. And [**according to W3Schools**](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_tablerow_insertcell.asp), `insertCell()` is supported in every browser. [**Mozilla says**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement/insertCell#Browser_compatibility) it's supported at least in Firefox in addition to IE. Are you getting any errors? Are you sure you're using valid JSON? You can verify it at [**JSONLint**](http://www.jsonlint.com).

Comment: @ObsidianAge I am getting no error code. Yes, I did check it is a valid JSON file.

Comment: `the code only works on Edge browser but not any other bowers` - what does your code do in other browsers? Have you tried any debugging, like adding `console.log`'s to your code to see what is and isn't being executed?

Comment: @JaromandaX,  this error shows up, how can i fix it ? 

Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: Search cors and chrome. You are using file protocol

Comment: This is a known limitation of Chrome, by default, it considers all AJAX when the page is loaded using `file` protocol to be cross origin - there is a command line flag to change this behaviour, however, I would recommend not using it, but rather, use a http server so that you are properly testing your code in a similar environment to production - sure, this may be a personal project so http server seems overkill, in that case, just use the command line switch for Chrome, not sure how to get around this in IE, probably a registry setting somewhere deep in the registry